# jquery AJAX stopped working with iOS 5.0.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ajax, ios5

The following piece of logic used to work with both jquery 1.4.4 and 1.7.1 on all mobile devices that we're supporting:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.example.com/someurl',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'text',
  timeout: 60000,
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR) {
    alert(jqXHR.state());
  }
});
```

But with iOS 5.0.1, the above enters the error function alerting `rejected` without any actual HTTP requests. It seems that exactly one AJAX request will work before I need to restart my iPhone.
Is this a known jquery / iOS 5.0 problem? How can I debug it? Is there any workaround? I don't know where to start looking.

**NOTE**: I've noticed on the server side, that instead of `GET` requests, `OPTIONS` requests are issued. This seems to be a related issue:

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/01/20/mobile-safari-on-ios-5-1-unexpectedly-making-cross-origin-resource-sharing-requests/

Comment: Have you looked at the traffic between the phone and the server using something like Charles?

Comment: @tkone: Hmm, yes I could find some traffic being blocked by our web entry server. It seems that the iPhone issues an `HTTP OPTIONS` request, which we reject... But why...?

Comment: that's very odd.  Do you have a sample page I can point my phone at?  I have an iOS4 device as well I want to see if it happens on as we are about redo our mobile site to rely extensively on ajax...

Comment: @tkone: Unfortunately, no. I can't make this publicly available... :-/ But iOS4 is still fine

Comment: @tkone: N.B. I'm starting to *feel* that iOS 5 doesn't send cookies with `XMLHttpRequest` :-/

Comment: @tkone: I found the issue. This might be interesting to you, too. Beware of PDF downloads on iOS 5!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link that I provided in the question is actually pointing to the solution. Some of my ajax requests are used to fetch URL's of PDFs which are streamed using

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somename.pdf"
```

Apparently, that causes major issues in iOS 5.0's Safari, breaking the `XMLHttpRequest` object (it is not related with jquery). Crazy. Here's the link again:

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/01/20/mobile-safari-on-ios-5-1-unexpectedly-making-cross-origin-resource-sharing-requests/

Comment: So it was the content-disposition header that is causing it to break?  You should file a bug at radar.apple.com about this -- I didn't find one when searching in there.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @tkone: Good idea! Filed as issue `10835750`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the investigation. I am having the same problem. After receiving a file as 'attachment' Mobile Safari sends OPTIONS request when calling:

```
$.ajax('/url')
```

BUT, if I run the following code from the same file, it generates a valid GET request:

```
http = new XMLHttpRequest()     
http.open("GET", "/url")
http.send()
```

Why jQuery is not working but XMLHttpRequest works here?

Answer (score -1):

> The reason for the error is the same origin policy. It only allows you
>   to do XMLHTTPRequests to your own domain. See if you can use JSON
>   instead.

References and recommended resources;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109261/896341
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: I'm sending the request to the same domain. All requests are sent to the real-life equivalent of `http://www.example.com`. `JSON` is not an option in our setup...