# Set content-disposition based on user agent in rails (workaround for iOS bug)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios

I'm hitting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210015/jquery-ajax-stopped-working-with-ios-5-0-1) bug in my application, where ajax in mobile safari stops working after receiving a response with `Content-Disposition:attachment`

I want to keep sending disposition:attachment to desktop browsers and to non-iOS mobile devices, while switching to disposition:inline on iOS.  I need to do this in a few different controller actions.

Is there an elegant way of doing this beyond putting these types of blocks all over the place?

```
if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /iPad/
    disposition = :inline
else 
    disposition = :attachment
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a `before_filter` in application controller that will set it once and for all!

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_content_disposition

  def set_content_disposition
    if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /iPad/
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline'
    elsif params[:format].in?(['pdf', 'other_format', 'other_format2'])
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment'
    end
  end
  #Rest of application controller code ...
end
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't set :attachment for *all* requests, because then the browser will try to download every page. Is there a way to set a header for all responses of a given format, so that every time I do `respond_to ... format.pdf` it sets the header?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach.